# C++ Read File being wiped at start of program using ofstream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a text file and output the contents. It's just I can't seem to find the right method and the ones I've used (including this one), seems to wipe the text file. The code:

```
std::string Line;
std::ifstream File("Account.txt");
if (File.is_open()) {
    while (getline(File, Line)) {
        std::cout << Line << std::endl;
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "Unable to open File" << std::endl;
}
File.close();
```

I'm also using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

I'm using this code (below) every time the program runs to create the file which might be the error, if so can anyone recommend a way to create the file only if it doesn't already exist

```
std::ofstream File("Account.txt");
File.close();
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work? What did you expect, and what actually happens?

Comment: Showing the full code may help us to help you.

Comment: @RohanBari I've edited it now, any suggestions?

Comment: The code you show is correct, there is no apparent reason for the behavior you describe unless there is some more code that you don't show.

Comment: You need to debug and single-step the program.  Inspect the local variables as they change.

Comment: @Evorage There's no error in your code and it seems to be working fine. That's why asked to give the full relevant code.

Comment: How are you invoking your program?

Comment: Your code is working: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/483d98174b6a86b9) (Please, note that it requires that the file `Account.txt` must be in current working directory.)

Comment: ive added the could-be-problem now

Comment: @Evorage Have you tried putting the code to create a new file inside of the `else` block? You won't be able to open the file if it doesn't exist. (i.e, `File.is_open()` will return `false`)

Comment: Opening and then immediately closing a `std::ofstream` with the default flags will create an empty file.

Comment: The code will make the file "Acount.txt" only when it is not already there. The possible reasons which make it to apparently wipe out text file are; either the "Account.txt" is not in the same file where the code is, or there is nothing written in "Account.txt". Make sure that "Account.txt" is in the same folder where the code is and that something is written in it.

Comment: @letsShareKnowlede That code will always wipe the "Account.txt" file, which is exactly what the OP is seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is being wiped by your file creating code.

```
std::ofstream File("Account.txt");
File.close();
```

To create a file without wiping existing contents try this

```
std::ofstream File("Account.txt", std::ios_base::app);
File.close();
```

Comment: ... and then use `File.tellp()` to figure out if the file is empty (it was probably just created) or not (it already existed), to avoid adding on the same contents over and over.